# The normal bundle of conic

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, vector-bundles, coherent-sheaves

Let $C\subset\mathbb{P}^2\subset\mathbb{P}^n$ be a smooth conic (everything is over the field $\mathbb{C}$). I want to compute $T_{\mathbb{P}^n|C}$ and $N_{C/\mathbb{P}^n}$.

Let $z_0,z_1,...,z_n$ be a homogeneous coordinates in $\mathbb{P}^n$ and suppose that $\mathbb{P}^2$ is given by $\{z_3=...=z_n=0\}$ and $C=\{z_0^2+z_1^2+z_2^2=0\}$. To compute $T_{\mathbb{P}^n|C}$ I use Euler sequence

$$0\to\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}\to\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(1)^{\oplus(n+1)}\to T_{\mathbb{P}^n}\to0.$$
Tensoring it with $\mathcal{O}_C$ we obtain the exact sequence
$$0\to\mathcal{O}_{C}\stackrel{\left(
\begin{array}{c}
z_0\\
z_1\\
z_2\\
0\\
\vdots\\
0\\
\end{array}
\right)}\to\mathcal{O}_{C}(1)^{\oplus(n+1)}\to T_{\mathbb{P}^n|C}\to0,$$
from which we have that $T_{\mathbb{P}^n|C}=F\oplus\mathcal{O}_{C}(1)^{\oplus(n-2)}$, where $F$ is the cokernel of the map
$$\mathcal{O}_{C}\stackrel{\left(
\begin{array}{c}
z_0\\
z_1\\
z_2
\end{array}
\right)}\to\mathcal{O}_{C}(1)^{{\oplus3}}.$$
Then $F$ is equal to $\mathcal{O}_{C}(1)\oplus\mathcal{O}_{C}(2)$ or $\mathcal{O}_{C}\oplus\mathcal{O}_{C}(3)$. What is the correct answer?

To compute $N_{C/\mathbb{P}^n}$ I use the exact sequence
$$0\to T_C\to T_{\mathbb{P}^n|C}\to N_{C/\mathbb{P}^n}\to0.$$
But $T_C=\mathcal{O}_C(1)$ so it seems that $N_{C/\mathbb{P}^n}=F\oplus\mathcal{O}_{C}(1)^{\oplus(n-3)}$. Is it correct?

Comment: $C$ is a complete intersection of a quadric and  $n-2$ hyperplanes. So, $N_{C/\mathbb{P}^3}=\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(1)^{n-2}\oplus \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(2)$. So, your $F=\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(1)\oplus \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(2)$.

Comment: Thank you, I missed that point about complete intersection. Also I am not sure that $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(1)|_C=\mathcal{O}_C(1)$. Is it correct?

Comment: The integers are confusing. They mean restrictions of $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n})k)$. So, if you want to identify with the usual line bundle on the line (which is really a conic), you will have to multiply everything with 2.

Comment: So, $F$ is actually the cokernel of the map $\mathcal{O}_{C}\stackrel{\left(
\begin{array}{c}
z_0\\
z_1\\
z_2
\end{array}
\right)}\to\mathcal{O}_{C}(2)^{{\oplus3}}$? How to compute this?